# "the job of a teacher being to make the facts and rules explicit and convey them to the student."

Tags: grammar

This is a sentence from an LSAT:

> Behind the hope that computers can replace teachers is the idea that
> the student's understanding of the subject being taught consists in
> knowing facts and rules, the job of a teacher being to make the facts
> and rules explicit and convey them to the student.

Regarding the latter part "the job of a teacher being ...", I am not sure what grammar is used here and why there is no conjunction.

Thank you very much,

Leon

Comment: I am not 100% sure, but I think that this is an adverbial participle clause.  When you use an adverbial participle clause you don't need a conjunction.

Comment: @stangdon: thank you so much! So why this is not a resumptive modifier but instead an adverbial participle clause?